# Парсинг сложной строки на python

Tags: python, парсер

недавно начал заниматься новым для себя языком ( phython): облазил инет не нашёл решения:
Есть строка вида:

```
«t=xx.x;h=xx.x;b=xxx;s=xx;sn=xxx;»
```

Необходимо вытащить данные обозначенные x в отдельные переменные..пример:

```
t=xx.x
h=xx.x
```

и т.д

Понимаю что для вас вопрос пустяковый, но прошу помочь новичку, в виде алгоритма понимаю как сделать, но кодом не получается.
 а значение отдельное переменной t= ( значению t в строке , тоесть"xx.x"
Python 3.7

Answer (score 4):

Это далеко не сложная строка. Поможет вам метод `split`:

```
a = "t=xx.x;h=xx.x;b=xxx;s=xx;sn=xxx;"
vars = a.split(";")
print(vars)
```

> ['t=xx.x', 'h=xx.x', 'b=xxx', 's=xx', 'sn=xxx', '']

Можно сделать вывод еще нагляднее:

```
for _ in vars:
    if len(_):
        print(_)
```

Получим:

```
t=xx.x
h=xx.x
b=xxx
s=xx
sn=xxx
```

**UPDATE**:

Если нужно получить пары "переменная - значение", то воспользуйтесь словарем:

```
a = "t=xx.x;h=xx.x;b=xxx;s=xx;sn=xxx;"
res = {x[0]:x[1] for x in [y.split("=") for y in a.split(";") if len(y)]}
print(res)
```

> {'t': 'xx.x', 'h': 'xx.x', 'b': 'xxx', 's': 'xx', 'sn': 'xxx'}

В таком случае переменную можно будет вызвать так:

```
print(res["sn"])
```

> xxx

Можно передать полученные пары в функцию `locals()`, но желательно, чтобы вы точно понимали, что делаете.

**UPDATE #2**

По уточнению автора вопроса могу предложить следующее решение:

```
message=b't=24.00;h=24.00;b=80;\x00?\xd6{"\xcc\xbe'
#вы получаете не строковую переменную, а байты. поэтому сначала декодируйте данные:
a = message.decode('ascii', errors='surrogateescape')
# либо
# a = message.decode('utf-8', errors='surrogateescape')
res = {x[0]:x[1] for x in [y.split("=") for y in a.split(";") if "=" in y]}
#обратите внимание на условие проверки для y (if "=" in y)
print(res)
```

> {'t': '24.00', 'h': '24.00', 'b': '80'}

И еще, обратите внимание, что когда вы делаете:

```
t = res["t"]
```

вы получаете строковую переменную. Если вам в дальнейшем придётся проводить с ней какие-то арифметические операции, сразу приводите ее к числовому типу:

```
t = float(res["t"])
```

Comment: Не совсем так , 
нужно получить не "t=xx.x", а значение отдельное переменной t= ( значению t в строке , тоесть"xx.x"

Comment: попробывал реализовать -  постоянная ошибка
сриншот и кода и ошибки по ссылке https://i.paste.pics/56ca390bbd30490a756464e5f6a705ff.png

Comment: @MaximKiryanov еще бы. у вас на входе не строка, а байты, кроме того, содержимое несколько не соответствует тому, что было написано в вопросе. Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

s = "t=xx.x;h=yy.y;b=zzz;s=12;sn=456;"
res = re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\s*=\s*([^=;]*)', s)
print(res)
#[('t', 'xx.x'), ('h', 'yy.y'), ('b', 'zzz'), ('s', '12'), ('sn', '456')]
```

или в виде словаря:

```
print(dict(res))
#{'t': 'xx.x', 'h': 'yy.y', 'b': 'zzz', 's': '12', 'sn': '456'}
```

PS [разбор и пояснение данного RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/WS0eZN/1)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробуем так:

```
l = "t=xx.x;h=xx.x;b=xxx;s=xx;sn=xxx;".split(";")
for e in l:
    if not e: continue
    k, v = e.split("=")
    locals()[k] = v
```

Ключевой момент — вызов функции [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), чтобы получить словарь с локальными переменными, куда добавляются новые значения. Потом их можно использовать.

```
print(t, h, s, sn)
```